# Start drag with another element

Tags: jquery, draggable

is it possible to start the drag with another element?

For example: http://jsbin.com/igohod/edit#preview

I want to start dragging `#ct` when I click on the `#icon`. Notably, `#icon` is not descended from `#ct` in the DOM tree.

**html**

```
  <div style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:10px;">
    <div id="icon">Icon</div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:absolute; top:20px; right:10px;">
    <div id="ct">start this drag when you drag the icon</div>
  </div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  // $('#icon').draggable();
  $('#ct').draggable();
});
```

**UPDATE:**
New example with sortable
http://jsbin.com/igohod/8/edit#preview

**Solution**
http://jsbin.com/igohod/13/edit#preview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works, but always appends it to the end of the list:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#icon').mousedown(function(e) {
     $('#ct').trigger(e);
   });
   $('#dropHere').sortable({ placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight' });
   $('#ct').draggable({ connectToSortable: '#dropHere' });
```

I also added the CSS style and dropped the nested div tags:

```
 #dropHere div{width:10; height:10; padding:10px; border:1px solid #000;}
```

http://jsbin.com/igohod/9/

Comment: I'm think the reason the new div only appears at the bottom of the sortable div's is that the mouse coordinates and the new div are never in the sortable div together...

Comment: I was correct.  If the div is moved to the cursor, sortable works normally.  http://jsbin.com/igohod/11/

Comment: Perfekt! I just add cursorAt: `{ top: 15, left: 225 }` to the draggable and it works really nice!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

```
$('#icon').draggable({drag: function(event, ui) {
    $("#ct").parent().css("top", 20 + parseInt($(this).css("top")));
    $("#ct").parent().css("left", 200 + parseInt($(this).css("left")));
}});
```

Just update the left and top values of #ct when you move the icon around.

Comment: I dont want to change the position from the icon :/ ... Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, my example was not so good. I want to drop the #ct into a sortable list. That is the reason why i try to "start" the draggble with an other element. here is an example: http://jsbin.com/igohod/6/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot wrap the two elements in a div and use that?

Comment: @Tank The icon must be static.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution using a helper to encapsulate the draggable object. This way you don't need to catch any mouse events or set any arbitrary positions. jQuery handles this for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $('#dropHere').sortable({ 
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).find('.drophandle').replaceWith(ui.helper);
      $(ui.helper).attr('style','');
    }
  });

  $('#icon').addClass('drophandle').draggable({
       connectToSortable: '#dropHere',
       cursorAt: { top: 15, left: 225 },
       helper: function() { return $('#ct')[0]; }
  });

});
```

http://jsbin.com/igohod/25