# How to drag element by clicking another element by using jQuery UI's draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Is there a way to click on element, but drag another element , by using jQuery UI's draggable plugin?
I have tried to use *handle* option, but it works only if the handle is inside of the draggable element.In my case handle element is not a child of the draggable element.

Comment: check this it may helps to you. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634147/start-drag-with-another-element`

Comment: @Gowri your link's demo doesn't work either

Comment: Check accepted answer Jsbin link. `http://jsbin.com/igohod/9/`

Comment: @Gowri Yeah, I have checked that in Chrome. Doesn't work.

Comment: I checked in chrome it's working.Click on icon div and start drag another div element is dragging. Try with another browser.